# Live Editing in WebSorm 11.0.3

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have been trying to configure the Live Editing for WebStorm 11.0.3 and can't get that done. I have already followed the steps provided on their JetBrains Website and lots of Youtube Videos but that doesn't work for me. Someone please list or refer the step by step guide to configure that. 
I am using Windows10, and WebStorm 11.0.3 with a Student License.
Thanking You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [JetBrains IDE Support](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji?hl=en) Chrome extension
2. Right-click on HTML file that you want to Live edit in the editor, select Debug. WebStorm will open that file in Chrome and start debug session.
3. Start editing the file, you'll changes you make in the browser.

Live edit works best for HTML and CSS files, it also works for JavaScript files (including Node.js): read more about it in [WebStorm blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/)

Comment: Thank You, this worked for me.
But I would like to add one thing that when I initiate Debug, the output window open wit a port number and that should match the Port which debug has initiated. 
So, "One can set that Port Number in Plugin Setting by right clicking the JB Icon on the Chrome Toolbar".